# 2 потока, чтение-запись в общий буфер

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть часть кода, которая выполняет 2 функции:

1. Захватывает кадр с экрана монитора.
2. Сжимает этот кадр с помощью ffmpeg и пишет в файл.

Так как и 1 и 2 операции занимают время, а 2 уж намного больше, то я решил их разнести по 2 разным потокам, чтоб они не ждали друг друга.

1. Сделать общий буфер, например, на 8 кадров (Да можно всего лишь и на 2-3),
2. Поток 1 получает кадр и пишет его в общий буфер.
3. Поток 2 читает буфер и берет оттуда кадр.
4. Поток 1 пишет всегда по кругу, если конец, то начинает писать сначала. Главное, он не может перезаписывать кадр, к которому получил доступ Поток 2.
5. Поток 1 не ждёт когда обработаются все кадры в буфере, он пишет поверх старых. То есть в итоге кадры могут пропускаться.
6. Общий буфер не должен блокироваться, если к нему получил доступ какой-либо из потоков. То есть он всегда доступен обоим потокам.

Как это реализовать? Кольцевой неблокируемый буфер, как?

Comment: Лучше будет захватывать и сжимать аппаратно. Тогда это все можно будет без проблем крутить в одном потоке.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте у каждого кадра в буфере свой mutex и индикатор состояния, принимающий значения -- "пусто" и "заполнен". Сначала все кадры находятся в состоянии "пусто". Также храните вместе с индикатором состояния последовательный номер, вырабатываемый Потоком 1 при заполнении кадра.

Поток 1 бежит по кольцу кадров и всегда делает только [pthread_mutex_trylock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock) для захвата кадра. Найдя кадр в состоянии "пусто", заполняет его, присваивает этим данным новый последовательный номер и оставляет в состоянии "заполнен" (естественно, снимает блокировку с кадра).

Если он не нашел свободного кадра в буфере, то он захватывает и переписывает новыми данными самый старый еще не обработанный кадр.

Поток 2 тоже в основном делает `pthread_mutex_tryloc()`,  найдя заполненный буфер обрабатывает его и переводит в состояние "пусто". Он никогда не должен обрабатывать кадр с последовательным номером меньшим или равным последнему, который он обработал. Если захватили кадр с таким номером, просто освобождайте `lock` и ищите следующий кадр, переводя этот в состояние "пусто".

Если Поток 2 прошел полный круг без работы, то поняв, что очередной кадр заполняется потоком 1 (т.е. `pthread_mutex_trylock()` вернул не 0 и `errno = EBUSY`), он вызывает [pthread_mutex_lock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) и таким образом ждет завершения заполнения кадра, не потребляя впустую такты процессора.
Получив в конце-концов `lock` на этот кадр, он его обрабатывает и опять начинает круг с `trylock()`.

Как-то так я вижу возможный алгоритм.

Answer (score 0):

Не имеет смысла разносить две взаимоувязанные операции в разные потоки в данном случае, постольку, поскольку во время сжатия кадра вы как раз занимаетесь пропуском других кадров, а сам процесс снятия скриншота будет только отнимать ресурсы ЦП, который и так нагружен сжатием.

Лучше подумать над ускорением самого процесса как снятия скриншотов, так и сжатия. В идеале - использовать аппаратный захват и аппаратное же сжатие, без передачи полного кадра в RAM. С последним может быть туго - разные производители имеют разные API для этого.

На Linux c Intel HD Graphics такой подход дает около 90 FPS, что лично я считаю хорошим результатом.

Answer (score 0):

Такие задачи встречаются очень часто. Общее их название "Задача производитель/потребитель". По английски "Produser/Consumer". Для решения этих задач разработан алгоритм, который называется "Алгоритм кольцевого буфера". Это абсолютно стандартная вещь, проверенная в тысячах приложений. Обычно используются кольцевые буферы с размером кратным степени 2.

Алгоритм этот описан во многих местах. Например, тут: http://cdeblog.ru/simple-ring-buffer
В этой статье не описан режим блокировки буфера через мьютексы, но он достаточно очевиден: охранять мьютексами нужно не сам буфер, а индексы чтения и записи.

Comment: При таком способе писатель будет тормозиться, пока поток 2 (в терминах вопроса ТС) не обработает данные. Он же (ТС), хочет  другого -- писатель всегда куда-то может писать, а компрессор (поток 2) обрабатывает сколько успеет.

Comment: @avp "писатель всегда куда-то может писать" - так как буферов бесконечного объёма не бывает, то это пожелание реализовать невозможно.

Comment: @avp "писатель будет тормозиться, пока поток 2 (в терминах вопроса ТС) не обработает данные" -  наиболее характерный пример: писатель - поток, считывающий сырую картинку с матрицы, а читатаель - поток, который пакует сырые изображения в видеопоток и передаёт их (к примеру) в сеть.

Comment: @avp очевидно, что раньше или позже, но **обязательно** возникнет ситуация, когда читатель не успеет пережевать входной поток. К примеру - сеть перегружена. Поскольку эта ситуация **типовая**, то варианты её преодоления предложены давным-давно.  Их всего два: 1) Жертвовать самыми старыми фреймами отбрасывая их и заполняя их новыми 2) Отбрасывать новые, пока не будет освобождён буфер. Других стратегий нет и быть не может.  Какую выбрать - зависит от специфики задачи. Надо согласовывать с заказчиком.

Comment: Пожалуй, стоит добавить, что количество элементов в кольцевом буфере сильно зависит от производителя. Если производитель выдаёт очередную порцию данных строго периодически, то достаточно всего двух буферов. Если потребитель успевает, то - успевает. А если не успевает, то хоть миллион буферов! А вот если пакеты данных прилетают случайно (тот густо, то пусто), то имеет смысл увеличить количество элементов кольцевого буфера.

Comment: Спасибо, я перечитал свой алгоритм и обратил внимание, что упустил момент, когда писатель не нашел свободного буфера. Пожалуй, надо обновить, указав, что в этом случае писатель затирает самые старые данные. Надеюсь, ТС прочел ваши комментарии ко мне и сделает нужные выводы.